# Better Android Coding

Tags: android, coding-style

What I am looking for is better coding with parameters such as memory management, faster processing and cleaner coding. Is there any set of Good Coding Guide for Android using which we can make better applications. For example;

Which of the following convention is better among them:

## EXAMPLE - 1

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sampleTextView);
tv.setText("Hello World");
```

-- OR --

```
((TextView)  findViewById(R.id.sampleTextView)).setText("Hello World");
```

## EXAMPLE - 2

```
BroadcastReceiver br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
      ...
      ...
}

IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(...);
registerReceiver(filter, br);
```

-- OR --

```
registerReceiver(new IntentFilter(), br);
```

-- OR --

```
registerReceiver(new IntentFilter(), new BroadcastReceiver());
```

Which will result in lesser memory usage and help in quicker garbage collection. I have seen both type of coding in Android Framework (in Gingerbread as well as Froyo).

I have been developing for more than a year on Android now and I think anyone can code but to code clean and proper is what makes the difference. Can someone suggest or help out from their experience and knowledge.

Comment: You might use [baksmali](http://code.google.com/p/smali/) to disassemble the bytecode and inspect it, but you won’t find any substantial differences.

Answer (score 4):

These kinds of micro-optimizations aren't really worth worrying about unless you've seen a significant performance hit in your application. In any case, I would guess that it's even possible that the compiler is able to deduce that Example 1a = Example 1b. The amount of performance difference between them would amount to a few hundred nanoseconds at best as tv is a reference and is cheap to move around.

My recommendation would be to code in such a way as to make it as readable to you and your team as possible. If you need better performance, better algorithms will help way more. If you've already used those better algorithms, then you should experiment with the profiler to figure out which is faster.

Answer (score 0):

For both examples that you give, there is no difference between the various alternatives that you mention.

If you want to dig into this at a deeper level, write up some sample code that you want to examine, compile it into a jar and then use a disassembler on it to see exactly what bytecode is being generated. You should see that the bytecode is essentially the same in each of your cases.

Answer (score 0):

Both your examples just mean nearly nothing in aspects like memory management or processor time. Compiler will inline the variables in both examples. And even if he didn't the overhead is just one object reference. No benchmark could show you such difference.

In such cases prefer to write readable code.

You should be more bothered about preformance in places it really worths - in database working or image/video processing.

AFAIK, there is no any special recommendations for android. All of them are general advices about working with memory, databases, network and so on.

Read [Effective Java](http://www.sixwhits.com/documentation/SuggsDocs/Java/Effective%20Java%20-%20Programming%20Language%20Guide.pdf) by Joshua Block, it will be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with everyone else that say that this type of optimization will do nothing that you can notice.

The only case in which you should consider optimizing is if you implement a complex draw method by hand or if you parse a big xml file (some changes might improve the running time).

Anyway, before optimizing, always measure.

> You can't optimize what you can't measure

To learn how to profile your application, read this

http://www.jpct.net/wiki/index.php/Profiling_Android_Applications

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the responses. After reading I think I completely agree with all you, especially  SapphireSun. Seeing both the kinds of coding, I was wondering whether inline has any pros or cons over the other types of coding.

But as far as I think that it is better to use declarations such as ((TextView)  findViewById(R.id.sampleTextView)).setText("Hello World"); instead of allocating it to a temporary variable because that would increase an object reference which will get garbage collected when GC is ticked. But with the declaration as above I guess there is no involvement of such object being left behind for GC.

Please correct me if I am wrong.